# Converting input stream into bitmap

Tags: java, android, multithreading, inputstream, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have problems converting a input stream from web into bitmap. Problem occurs only when input image type is .BMP (bitmap). In that case: **bitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null**.

Any hints how to fix this problem or where should I continue my debugging?

Platform: Android (Honeycomb)

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.connect();

inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);
```

Comment: Are there any log error than can help?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Thank you @Amir for point out the log. Discovered a line:

```
decoder->decode returned false
```

This seems to be a common problem. Doing a search I found a solution.

**My previous code:**

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.connect();

inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);
```

**Code which is working:**

```
HttpGet httpRequest = null;

try {
    httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);

InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();

bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);
```

[Source](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/10a3821158f17be1)

Comment: I use WCF Service and when I send byte[] of image and used your method to convert back to bitmap image, but BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream) is always null!!

Answer (score 10):

**Here is a one-line answer**

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
```

Returns a `Bitmap`

Comment: Feel free to use this for getting local images for example