# Receiving image from socket in Android

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting input stream into bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612263/converting-input-stream-into-bitmap)

I am trying to receive multiple images sent as byte array over sockets via `BitmapFactory.decodeInputStream(Input Stream)` method but I get the error message: `Decoder returned false.`

Here is my code:

```
while(true)
{   
    this.image=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(image);

    if(!notreceiving)
    {           
        pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        loadingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        notreceiving=true;
    }           
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612263/converting-input-stream-into-bitmap