# How to replace alert dialog single choice radio button text into images?

Tags: android, json, android-alertdialog

This is my actual JSON response from server. Here 3rd object contains url.
In android alert dialog single choice when get 3rd object, I need those radio options in images.

```
{  
   "quiz":[  
      {  
         "time":10,
         "q_id":"1",
         "label":"1.First Question",
         "option":[  
            "a",
            "b",
            "c",
            "d"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "time":20,
         "q_id":"2",
         "label":"2.Second Question",
         "option":[  
            "e",
            "f",
            "g",
            "h"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "time":50,
         "q_id":"3",
         "label":"3.Third Question",
         "option":[  
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcShqRPmJQo0Jw20ryifdlUUm4iFuEGktmEfCZaEM8lJITVxNnK4rw",
            "https://drop.ndtv.com/albums/SPORTS/ct2017_ind_pak/thumb_640x480.jpg",
            "https://drop.ndtv.com/albums/SPORTS/ct2017_ind_pak/thumb_640x480.jpg",
            "https://drop.ndtv.com/albums/SPORTS/ct2017_ind_pak/thumb_640x480.jpg"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

This is my android code. Here I need to change the radio button text into image. In case json object get as URL. How can get those?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                                try {
                                                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("option"));

                                                    if (time == Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("time"))) {
                                                        running = false;
                                                        mp.pause();

                                                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Page03.this);
                                                        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

                                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new ActionBar.
                                                                LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                                        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
                                                        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

                                                        final TextView alertdiaglogtitle = new TextView(Page03.this);//title
                                                        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/sffb.ttf");//custom font

                                                        alertdiaglogtitle.setTypeface(face);
                                                        alertdiaglogtitle.setTextSize(20);
                                                        alertdiaglogtitle.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
                                                        alertdiaglogtitle.setLayoutParams(params);
                                                        alertDialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(alertdiaglogtitle);

                                                        alertdiaglogtitle.setText(jsonObject.getString("label"));

                                                        final String quetionid = jsonObject.getString("q_id");

                                                        for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {

                                                            timing.add(array.get(j).toString());
                                                            if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(array.get(j).toString()).matches()) {
                                                                Toast.makeText(Page03.this, "valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            } else {
                                                                Toast.makeText(Page03.this, "Not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            }
                                                        }

                                                        CharSequence[] cs = timing.toArray(new CharSequence[timing.size()]);
                                                        timing.clear();

                                                        alertDialogBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(cs, -1, new DialogInterface
                                                                .OnClickListener() {
                                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {


                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                                                                        ListView lw = ((AlertDialog) arg0).getListView();
                                                                        checkedItem = (String) lw.getAdapter().getItem(lw.getCheckedItemPosition());

                                                                        Toast.makeText(Page03.this, quetionid.toString() + "------" + checkedItem.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                                        arg0.dismiss();
                                                                        mp.start();
                                                                        running = true;
                                                                    }
                                                                });

                                                        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                                finish();

                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                                                        alertDialog.show();
                                                    }
                                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }

                                            }
```

Comment: You need to download the images then load them into custom layout inside the alertdialog

Comment: Already i'm also think like that but any other way???
if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(array.get(j).toString()).matches()) {
                                                                Toast.makeText(Page03.this, "valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            } else {
                                                                Toast.makeText(Page03.this, "Not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            }
here once return valid i need to create image view.

Comment: to read them as InputStream check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612263/converting-input-stream-into-bitmap